# How to not digest *.html template files in assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, assets, sprockets, digest

I have html templates files in assets folder for angular. In production sprockets digest these files. And I can't reference to them from angular directive.

For example:
templateUrl: @template('index.html')

but real file name is index-34857398782634287.html

How to not digest html files?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy them to `/public` directory. Asset Pipeline don't process files in this directory.

Comment: This is not convenient for me because I splitted JS for components. Component folder has directive, controller and view.